# Appium Android 12.0 Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra and Google Pixel 3 C# - System.NotImplementedException : Unknown mobile command "scroll"

Tags: c#, scroll, appium-android

I'm trying to execute scripts for Android, are their any scroll scripts for Android?

I see we have for iOS https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#platform-specific-extensions

```
driver.ExecuteScript("mobile: scroll", new Dictionary<string, string>() { {"direction","down" } });
```

> System.NotImplementedException : Unknown mobile command "scroll". Only shell,scrollBackTo,viewportScreenshot,deepLink,startLogsBroadcast,stopLogsBroadcast,acceptAlert,dismissAlert,batteryInfo,deviceInfo,changePermissions,getPermissions,performEditorAction,startScreenStreaming,stopScreenStreaming,getNotifications,listSms,type commands are supported.

> Stack Trace:?
> RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
> RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
> RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
> RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)

Appium Android 12.0 Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra and Google Pixel 3 C#

Help in finding scroll script or similar method to scroll to the element in Android Appium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command should be "mobile: scrollGesture".

Here's the documentation: https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver/blob/master/docs/android-mobile-gestures.md#mobile-scrollgesture

Answer (score 0):

For "mobile: scroll", arguments such as strategy and selector are mandatory for Android UiAutomator2 mobile commands

Link: [appium-uiautomator2-driver#mobile-scroll](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver#mobile-scroll)

Code:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dic.Add("strategy", "-android uiautomator");
dic.Add("selector", "UiSelector().textContains(\"Asia\")");

driver.ExecuteScript("mobile: scroll", dic);
```